zsh: command not found: yt-dlp
The standalone executable yt-dlp recommended for macOS suddenly stopped working. I used it two weeks ago and it worked. I have not had any updates to my system, expect some brew updates/upgrades.
Every time the command is run: zsh: command not found: yt-dlp
I did not find any relevant issues on the official repository. I re-installed the binary a few times and ensured it's not a path issue.
None of the similar questions with zsh: command not found match my problem.
Output of echo $PATH:
/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/Resources/utilities

"I re-installed it the binary a few times and experimented with path" where did you put the binary and what's the output from echo "$PATH"?

"zsh: command not found: yt-dlp" - this means exactly what it says: the command yt-dlp cannot be found (by the shell zsh) by searching through the directories listed in $PATH

@ChrisDavies sorry for making this unclear. I had a directory in home called standalone executables where the binary was moved. As it's not a standard location, I tried the running yt-dlp after moving it to home. This was both pre and after re-install.

Any reason you've listed $PATH twice? You're missing the absolute path to your standalone executables, which is why your Mac can't find yt-dlp

You have Homebrew already installed, to install yt-dlp:
brew install yt-dlp
brew upgrade yt-dlp

Returning to the problem, the binary isn't in your PATH or you have used an invalid binary. Here is how to install the executable. See here.
curl -L https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp/releases/latest/download/yt-dlp_macos -o ~/.local/bin/yt-dlp
chmod a+rx ~/.local/bin/yt-dlp 

Check if ~/.local/bin is in your $PATH (by echo $PATH), if not, add it.

I have issues with yt-dlpwith brew. As fas as I've seen, there are plenty of issues with it in general. I installed and upgraded the binary and the output on running it is a very, very long error (~10000 characters)

You're missing the absolute path to your standalone executables from $PATH, which is why your Mac can't find yt-dlp. (The $PATH variable contains an ordered colon-separated list of directories in which to search for commands.)
If standalone executables was actually /some/path/to/standalone executables you could add it (temporarily) like this:
PATH="$PATH:/some/path/to/standalone executables"

To make this change permanent you would need to add it to an appropriate zsh initialisation file
